# The [semi-?] official CSS validator complains about some MS CSS

Tags: css, validation

I ran Site.css (mostly Microsoft-supplied CSS, with maybe 5% added by me) against http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator, and it told me I had two errors:

```
.featured .content-wrapper   Value Error : background-image left is not a color value )
.boldHeader  Value Error : font-style bold is not a font-style value : bold
```

I removed the second one (which was my error), but the first one was this MS CSS:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
```

What is wrong with it?

BTW, it also gives me these warnings:

```
Property -webkit-box-sizing is an unknown vendor extension
Property -moz-box-sizing is an unknown vendor extension
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Syntax), you need to specify an angle or a direction as the first parameter to `gradient()`:

```
Formal grammar: linear-gradient(  [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+ )
```

You're missing the `to` in front of `left`.

Comment: If I change it to "toleft" or "to-left", it gives the same err msg.

Comment: it's `to left`, with a space.  I tried that in the validator and it passed.

Comment: Interesting; I claim the million dollar prize from Microsoft for finding an egregious bug; I'll share it with you.

Comment: Resharper also caught it; and when I tried to prepend the "to " to the "left" Intellisense added "tomato"!